# php create table vertically from array

Tags: php, arrays, html

Hi I found this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047757/php-create-table-from-array)
, but it doesnt do exactly what i'm looking for.

I would like the table to be displayed like this instead:

```
   **     | array1         | array2 
           -------------------------------
 logtime   | 1305732210     | 1305732216
           -------------------------------
 useragent | Mozilla        | Mozilla
           -------------------------------
```

Edited:

my bad for not posting code, but here is what i'm stuck on.

i have this query that outputs an array of data from mysql

```
SELECT s.*, m.id AS wmMake
                                  FROM `table1` AS s
                                  JOIN `table2` AS m
                                  WHERE s.code = m.code
            AND (s.ic='123'
            OR s.ic='1234"
```

its output looks like this

```
Array ( [0] => PAS [cat] => PAS [1] => H4B12A [ic] => H4B12A [2] => SMALL [segment] => SMALL [3] => 6 [wmMake] => 6 ) 
Array ( [0] => PAS [cat] => PAS [1] => HUV12A [ic] => HUV12A [2] => SMALL [segment] => SMALL [3] => 6 [wmMake] => 6 )
```

Now on my php side i have this:

```
for ($i =0; $c = mysql_fetch_array($query); $i++)
{
   print_r($c); 
}
```

the for loop, loops through 1 row at a time, how do i loop through each row, and get the 1st value and, then each row again to get 2nd value of array and so on. My html output should look like this.

```
    **     | array1         | array2 
           -------------------------------
 cat       | PAS            | PAS
           -------------------------------
 ic        | H4B12A         | HUV12A
           -------------------------------
 segment   | SMALL          | SMALL
           -------------------------------
  wmMake   | 6              | 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the array keys first. And then loop through the keys and echo the values from both the arrays.

```
$keys = array_keys($arr1, $arr2);

echo "<table>";
foreach($keys as $k) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$k."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$arr1[$k]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$arr2[$k]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: My guess is that user2035819 wants to have each record in the array viewed in a new column. As http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047757/php-create-table-from-array does it per row. Though this isn't clearly asked in the question...

Comment: edited my question. sorry for the lack of info

Comment: @user2035819 in your for loop, just make two arrays $arr1 and $arr2 that you want to display in vertical. Then ourside your for loop, run my above code, it will handle the rows and columns as you want.

Answer (score 4):

1. Know how to construct a HTML table
2. Know how to use `arrays` and how they work with `keys` and `values`.
3. Know how to use `for` loops, or `foreach` loops on `arrays`.
4. Combine the knowledge above, and create what you want.

Comment: You can vote me down, but its really you, who is asking to do work, instead of wanting to learn what is necessary. Do you want me to add references to W3C definition of tables? And links to PHPs website on arrays and loops?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can know for sure that both/all the arrays have the exact same keys, you can do with with foreach:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
{
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$array1[$key].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$array2[$key].'</td>';
   // ... etc
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

I will note however that Mike de Klerk's answer is relevant and should not be disregarded—StackOverflow is not for having code written for you or teaching you how to write code, it's for getting answers about specific things you're stuck on.